# Set multiple lines programmatically

Tags: android

---- New code: ----
How is it possible with this new code to add an extra line with a smaller font? Expected output should be this:

Hamburger ($2)

*Good beef with salad*

Pizza ($3)

*With much cheese*

Chicken Nuggets ($4)

*With the best sauce*

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Food (€4)", "Food also (€3)", "Food again (€2,50)" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }
}
```

---- Old code: ----

I'd like to place a 'menu list' programmatically.. Something like this as output:

Hamburger
*Good beef with salad*

Pizza
*With much cheese*

Chicken Nuggets
*With the best sauce*

At this point all the sentences are programmed seperately:

```
TextView mContent = new TextView(this);
mContent.setText("Hamburger");
mContent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
mContent.setPadding(32, 8, 32, 0);
mContent.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(mContent);

TextView mContent2 = new TextView(this);
mContent2.setText("TextView mContent = new TextView(this);
        //mContent.setText("Broodje hamburger (€6)\nBroodje hotdog (€4,50)\nPizza (€7)\nSpaghetti (€5)");
        mContent.setText("Broodje hamburger (€6)");
        mContent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        mContent.setPadding(32, 8, 32, 0);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(mContent);

        TextView mContent2 = new TextView(this);
        mContent2.setText("Met echt rundbeef, sla, tomaten en een lekker sausje");
        mContent2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
        mContent2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        mContent2.setPadding(32, 0, 32, 16);
        mContent2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(mContent2);");
mContent2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
mContent2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
mContent2.setPadding(32, 0, 32, 16);
mContent2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(mContent2);
```

Is there an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). It is used to display a list of things in an arrnaged manner as you need now.

See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial.

To customise you layout you will have to create a custom adapter that defines the view of a single item.

StableArrayAdapter.java

```
// define your custom adapter
    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<String> items1;
        ArrayList<String> description1;

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> items, ArrayList<String> description) {

            // let android do the initializing :)
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items1=items;
            this.description1 = description;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position == this.getCount() - 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView item;
            TextView desc;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
                viewHolder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.item.setText(items1.get(position).toString());
            viewHolder.desc.setText(description1.get(position).toString());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

    }
```

single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, same comment as MikeKeepsOnShine: When checking the Vogel tutorial, I used the example code from chapter 2. But instead of a list, the only result is the first item of the list (e.g.: "Android"). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My mistake.. The height was very small and only showed one result.. The other results were visible by scrolling

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to add a second line (which has a smaller and italic font)? I will update my main code..

Comment: Yes. You need to create a custom layout for that.

Comment: @0846277 I can't understand why you haven't accepted my answer, that i posted before the one that you've accepted and it seems pasted from mine

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine both answers were 18 hours ago.. I didn't know which one was first.. I can't accept both answers + I had a convo with K Neeraj..

Comment: @0846277 if you go on hover with cursor on the line "answered 19 hours ago", you can see the hours. Anyway, i don't want to argue ;-)
Just curiosity: you have accepted my answer before, right?

Comment: We are going completely off-topic. Both answers are now "answered 19 hours ago". Yes I have accepted your answer, but also the answer of K Neeraj.. There can only be one accepted answer, so the other answer wasn't accepted anymore.

Comment: @KNeerajLal In the StableArrayAdapter.java class I get multiple errors on: `super(context, textViewResourceId, name);` the name. In the class `getView` I also get an error on the name: `viewHolder.name.setText(items1.get(position).toString());` and lastly on the inflater: `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, parent, false);` In my main activity I have the following code, is this correct?: `StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, item, desc);
            list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @KNeerajLal Thanks for the edit. I assume that `super(context, textViewResourceId, name);` needs to be: `super(context, textViewResourceId, items);`. The final error is with the inflater.. `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, parent, false);` But the inflater is giving an error (cannot resolve symbol 'inflater')

Comment: Sorry about the typos. I reused code from an i made app and changed the values for you. Good luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView` and `Adapter`.

In the documentation, it's explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Here's a nice Lars Vogel tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Using `ListView` with `Adapter` you can manage every single item of your list.